# Starting up Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I found `quarkus` to be a good piece in the JAVA ecosystem. I am facing some challenges while trying to develop API with `quarkus`. It started initially and unable to start again after I exited the terminal.

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:732]
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the debug port already being bound.

You probably have some remaining process occupying the port you're trying to bind with.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally i have gotten working again.**

- I had to find what's making use of port 5005.
- Killed it.
- Then started the quarkus app again.

Thanks to you @Guillaume Smet

Comment: Accepting the answer (and probably deleting this one) would make it easier for others to look for whenever they stumble upon something similar.